# Yii application vs User loads

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have created a CRM application using Yii framework, it works well when user is less, when user connected increases say above **250 users**, ***the performance of application is too slow,***

I have tested via [Load Impact](https://app.loadimpact.com/), but i can able to test only 100 users

can anyone suggest how to get rid of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scaling problem. You have a few options:

1. **Scale up:** Upgrade the server to a higher configuration. (Need $$$)
2. **Scale out:** Deploy your app to more than one servers and configure a load balancer to distribute traffic to them. You may also need a centralized session store (e.g. yii\redis\Session) to ensure sessions persist across different nodes. (Need $$$ + Time)
3. **Optimize your app:** Review the code to find out which parts are slow and see if they can be optimized. (Need time)

Which one is best for you depends on situations (e.g. the money / time / technical knowledge or your team)